# Combining rows numpy to one single array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a while statement that produces an array in numpy

```
while(i<int(sp)): 
   body=(np.bincount(un[i].ravel().astype('int'), weights=step_periods[i].ravel())) 
   print(body) 
   i=i+1
```

each iteration produces an array of like the following:

```
1st    [  0.   0.   0.  30.]

2nd    [  0.   0.  21.  18.  15.]

3rd    [  0.  24.  27.   0.   3.]
```

My first issue is that if the first array has "0" as the last value, it will leave it out of the array. Is there a way to convert it from:

```
[  0.   0.   0.  30.]
```

to:

```
[  0.   0.   0.  30.  0.]
```

From there I would like to simply append each array to a master array so that the final output is something similar to:

```
    [[  0.   0.   0.  30.  0.0],

    [  0.   0.  21.  18.  15.],

   [  0.  24.  27.   0.   3.]]
```

I've looked into appending and vstack, but can't get it to work in a "while" statement, or possibly because they aren't all the same size due to the ending "0" being ommited!

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to show the `while` loop that is generating these subarrays.

Comment: You should post that as an edit to the post.  Putting it in comments makes it quite difficult to tell what is going on.

Comment: Sorry I'll do this right now, I'm new to these forums! I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem.  we're here to help :)

Comment: I'm not a `numpy` expert... but `from itertools import izip_longest; np.vstack(izip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue=0.)).T` works... - requires Py2.6+ I believe...

Comment: @JonClements -- I was actually considering posting something like that as a solution. ;)

Comment: @mgilson sorry - I wasn't willing to post it as a solution as I didn't want to end up looking like a "numpty" (see what I did there *cough*) if there was some other way... There must be someway to concat/stack/join (whatever term is supposed to be used) to do this in numpy

Comment: @JonClements -- That's basically what you're doing in your solution.  Personally, I would rather pre-allocate the whole thing (if there's any way to figure out the dimensions) since that will probably be faster than appending at each turn.  The one downside (upside?) about your solution is that the memory layout is opposite what you might expect (which can have performance issues, depending on how the rows/columns are accessed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution -- if you can guarantee that the length of `body` is always going to be less than (or equal to) 5, you can pre-allocate the array:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.zeros((int(sp)-i,5),dtype=int)
for ii in range(i,int(sp)):
    body=(np.bincount(un[i].ravel().astype('int'), weights=step_periods[i].ravel())) 
    my_array[ii,:len(body)]=body
```

You could even add a check to see if body got too wide and create a new array, assigning the old portion into it ... But at that point, maybe a stacking operation is what is needed.

Comment: Can you explain what ii is? and I get the error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3) (4)"

Comment: Looking at the np.zeros i think that the 5, and the int(sp)-i should be switched. But when I do switch it, i get the error

"invalid index"

Comment: after switching them, I realized my i=i+1 was not indented! THANK YOU! :) it works perfectly!

Comment: @EricEscobar -- You're right, they should have been switched.  (sorry about that)

Comment: could you point me somewhere I could learn more about what this means "my_array[ii,:len(body)]=body " it works well for what I need I just want to understand it more. Thank you again!

Comment: @EricEscobar -- This is basic slicing.  Look up numpy slicing and hopefully it will become more clear.

Comment: --is there a reason why the variable "body" would produce a float 7.3, but when put through `my_array[ii,:len(body)]=body ` would then be 7? Is there a way that i could have it produce the float?

Comment: @EricEscobar -- Sorry, for some reason I was under the impression you wanted ints (hence the `dtype=int` in the `np.zeros`.  Just remove that and you'll get your floats.